# A presentation of $C_4$ with one generating symbol $b$ and two defining relators.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

This is [Exercise 1.1.5(c)](https://books.google.com/books?id=1LW4s1RDRHQC&pg=PA9) of *"Combinatorial Group Theory: Presentations of Groups in Terms of Generators and Relations,"* by Magnus *et al.*

### The Question:

> Give a presentation of $C_4$ using one generating symbol $b$ and two defining relators, neither of which is $b^4$ or $b^{-4}$.

### My Attempt:

We have $$C_4=\langle b\mid b^2=b^{-2}, b^6=b^2\rangle,$$ but this doesn't seem to be in the spirit of the question.

Please help :)

---

Is this correct?

Here $b^4=b^{12}b^{-8}=1\cdot 1=1$ is a defining relator and so $$\langle b\mid b^8, b^{12}\rangle$$ is the presentation since $\langle b\mid b^4\rangle$ is a presentation.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think that should be an answer, not a comment. But thank you. I did have that as my answer (at least in part: I said that $b^8$ and $b^{12}$ are the relators), but I deleted it after you said it didn't answer the question.

Comment: I was just being pedantic. But in an exam or homework question you need to write down the answer to the question asked, not just a description of the answer in words.

Comment: @DerekHolt Fair enough.

Comment: @DerekHolt You have an unnecessary $c$ in your presentation.

Comment: Yes! It should be $\langle b \mid b^8,b^{12}\rangle$.